# Reformatting Dictionary output in python

Tags: python, csv, formatting, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDict and I've exported it to a csv but I want it to be formatted differently.

My code for reading, sorting, and making the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

counts = defaultdict(lambda: {"User": 0, "Equipment": 0, "Neither": 0})
with open('sorterexample.csv', 'rb') as fh: 
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',') 
    headerline = reader.next()
    for row in reader: 
        company, calltype = row[0], row[2]
        counts[company][calltype] += 1
        sorted_counts = OrderedDict(sorted(counts.iteritems(), key=lambda   counts_tup: sum(counts_tup[1].values()), reverse=True))

print(sorted_counts)
    writer = csv.writer(open('sortedcounts.csv', 'wb'))
    for key, value in sorted_counts.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

My ouput:

```
OrderedDict([('Customer1', {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 1, 'User': 4}), ('Customer3', {'Equipment': 1, 'Neither': 1, 'User': 2}), ('Customer2', {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 1}), ('Customer4', {'Equipment': 1, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 0})])
```

My CSV:

```
Customer1,  {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 1, 'User': 4}
Customer3,  {'Equipment': 1, 'Neither': 1, 'User': 2}
Customer2,  {'Equipment': 0, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 1}
Customer4,  {'Equipment': 1, 'Neither': 0, 'User': 0}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Top Calling Customers,         Equipment,    User,    Neither,
Customer 1,                      0,           4,        1,
Customer 3,                      1,           2,        1,
Customer 2,                      0,           1,        0,
Customer 4,                      1,           0,        0,
```

How can I format it so it shows up this way in my csv?

edit: I've looked at https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html, itemgetter(), and sorting dictionaries by values in python ([How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python?rq=1)) but I still can't make it look how I want it to.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv

Comment: @kponz To be honest, I didn't find it particularly helpful as he/she was trying to get the dictionary back to a CSV... which I don't have a problem with. It's the formatting that I can't get to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will format it the way you described: First it writes a header row using the first entry in the list to figure out the names for the columns and then it writes the rest of the rows.

```
writer = csv.writer(open('sortedcounts.csv', 'wb'))
header = ['Top Calling Customers'] + list(list(sorted_counts.values())[0].keys())
writer.writerow(header)
for key, value in sorted_counts.items():
    writer.writerow([key] + list(value.values()))
```