# Print array from dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary

I have dictionary like this (key:[array]):

```
{'person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge'],'person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes']}
```

and I would like to print this to CSV and make one column for each element of an array, so the result should like (header is optionable):

```
Owner,Car_1,Car_2
person1@gmail.com, BMW, Dodge
person2@gmail.com, Mercedes
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file-python

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python `csv` module.

```
import csv

d = {'person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge'],'person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes']}

with open('Cars.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(['Owner', 'Car_1', 'Car_2'])
    for k, v in d.items():
        spamwriter.writerow([k] + v)
```

[image]

Comment: I used the same as in my example: d={'person1@mail.com': ['BMW', 'Dodge'],'person2@mail.com': ['Mercedes']}

Comment: The code snippet that I posted gives the result shown in pic for python3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.writer`, assuming your data is stored in dictionary `d`

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(['Owner','Car_1','Car_2'])
    for key, val in d.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + val)
```