# Search a 2 dimensional python list for last occurrence in a particular column

Tags: python, list

I have a list with [vehicle name, number]

```
a=[["car","A1"],["car","A2"],["truck","A1"]]
```

I need a function such that if i specify

car it should return "A2" the last number in that vehicle name.
If i specify bike it should return "A0"

I tried writing something but keep getting an error list index out of range

**EDIT:**

here's the full list format

```
["vehicle","color","vehicle_num","status(True/False)","code"]
```

vehicle and color is given and last vehicle_num should be found, if vehicle,color doesn't exist `return "A0"`

The number system starts from "A1",.........."An"

n varies according to the vehicle,color

list is already sorted

Comment: Please update your code.

Comment: Your job would be easier and efficient if you used a dictionary.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I've added more details to the question

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a dictionary

You can take advantage of the fact `dict` assigns values in order and `list` is an ordered collection. So, for duplicate keys within your list of lists, the last mapping persists.

```
a = [["car","A1"], ["car","A2"], ["truck","A1"]]

d = dict(a)

print(d['car'])    # A2
print(d['truck'])  # A1
```

Revert to `list` if you need to afterwards (which you don't, as you can [write to csv from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv)).

```
res = list(map(list, d.items()))

print(res)

[['car', 'A2'], ['truck', 'A1']]
```

Comment: I need it to be a list because i store it in a csv file later

Comment: how would you use a dictionary for the edited part of the question?

Comment: `res = list(map(list, d.items()))`. Here, `d` is the dictionary from the first part. We convert dictionary key-value pairs, as demonstrated, to a list of lists.

Comment: how would you store this in a dictionary `["vehicle","color","vehicle_num","status(True/False)","code"]`

Comment: @NoelDSouza, For your new requirement, you should ask a new question with a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
def search(l, word):
    res = "A0"
    for i in l:
        if i[0] == word:
            res
    return res
```

You can then optimise it by saving "An" as Tupel of A with an integer n.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = {'car':['A1', 'A2'], 'bike':['A0'], 'truck': ['A1']}

def return_last(vehicle):
  return a[vehicle][-1]

return_last('car')
```