# Store dictionary with list values in csv using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

This is my dictionary structure

```
dic = {'tt3832096': ['remake', 'horror-movie-remake', 'flesh-eating-virus', 'gore'],
       'tt6217804': ['chainsaw', 'sequel', 'second-part', 'mable-simmons-character']}
```

I want to save it in csv file like this:

```
movie id      keyword
tt3832096     ['remake', 'horror-movie-remake', 'flesh-eating-virus', 'gore']
tt6217804     ['chainsaw', 'sequel', 'second-part', 'mable-simmons-character']
```

I have tried this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in dic.keys():
        f.write("%s:%s\n"%(key,dic[key]))
```

But it places each term of value in a cell. Is there a better way?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are plenty of sources for this. Check our [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv).

Comment: A proper csv structure would be to have one line per movie_id/keyword pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a 3rd party library, this is trivial with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# construct dataframe from dictionary d
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['movie id', 'keyword'])

# export to csv
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Really, though, this is **not** recommended if you plan to read the file back into Python. In this situation, you can use Pickle (version dependent) to store and pick up your dictionary with list values:

```
import pickle

with open('d_file.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(d, fout, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('d_file.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
    d = pickle.load(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.writer` with tabs as the delimiter:

```
import csv
d = {'tt3832096': ['remake', 'horror-movie-remake', 'flesh-eating-virus', 'gore'], 'tt6217804': ['chainsaw', 'sequel', 'second-part', 'mable-simmons-character']}
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['movie id', 'keyword'])
    for k, v in d.items():
        writer.writerow([k, v])
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines you showed, like this:

```
 tt3832096     ['remake', 'horror-movie-remake', 'flesh-eating-virus', 'gore']
```

are not part of a CSV file or, at least, not a CSV file with the structure you're thinking of.  As a CSV record, this is a line with four values which look like this (or something like this, depending on how quote characters are treated when decoding).

```
 tt3832096     ['remake'
 'horror-movie-remake'
 'flesh-eating-virus'
 'gore']
```

If you really want to save this as a CSV file, your best bet would be something that looks like this:

```
 'tt3832096', 'remake', 'horror-movie-remake', 'flesh-eating-virus', 'gore'
```

which should be similar to what you're producing now.

If you want to store it in a format that is more like the dictionary it came from, you have a few options:

1. Grow your own format (like the one you described) and read and write it as text (not using a CSV library).
2. Use the built-in Python serialization library `pickle` which will preserve the structure but produces files that are not human readable.
3. Use JSON serialization using one of the `json` libraries, which produces human readable, standard json files that can preserve dictionary structures.