# How to export dictionary with multiple values in Excel file

Tags: python, dictionary, spyder

I have a dictionary with multiple values to a key. For ex:

```
dict = {u'Days': [u'Monday', u'Tuesday', u'Wednesday', u'Thursday'],u'Temp_value':[54,56,57,45], u'Level_value': [30,34,35,36] and so on...}
```

I want to export this Data to excel in the below-mentioned formet.

```
Column 1   Column 2      column 3      so on...
Days       Temp_value    Level_value
Monday     54            30
Tuesday    56            34
Wednesday  57            35
Thursday   45            36
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Dictionary to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv)

Comment: @prashantrana Op wants to export to excel. However it is possible that this is a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_dict)
df.to_excel('your_file.xlsx', index=False)
```