# How to retrieve nested data with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the below webpage source:

```
</li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL 
      MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO">
        <a href="link1">
            <div class="title">BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO</div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,600</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Miami
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Honda Element">
        <a href=" link2 ">
            <div class="title">Honda Element</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,950</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Coral springs
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Mint Jeep">
        <a href=" link3 ">
            <div class="title">Mint Jeep</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$8,500</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Pompano
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I need to extract the data as below:

```
| URL  | TITLE               | PRICE  |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ |
| link1 | BELLO HONDA ACCORD | $4,600 |
| link2 | Honda Element      | $4,950 |
| link3 | Mint Jeep          | $8,500 |
```

I am able to extract the URL names. When I attempt to get the title and price, it seems I am entering a loop that get the title/price for the full page after each URL link I get. Below is my code:

```
from urllib import request 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import csv
page_url = 'URLNAME'
rawpage = request.urlopen(page_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage, 'html5lib')

links_list = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):              
    try:
       url = link.get('href')
    
       for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'title'}):
         title = div.text
         print (title)


        links_list.append({'url': url})
    # if the row is missing anything...
    except AttributeError:
        #....skip it, dont blow up.
        pass

    # save it to csv
    with open('links.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    # Creta the header rows
    csv_writer.writerow(['url', 'title'])

    for row in links_list:
    csv_writer.writerow([str(row['url'])])
```

Comment: Your indentation is a mess and makes it very hard to visually parse your code. Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: Sorry I copied it from Jupyter Notebooks. What do you mean mixing tabs and soaces?

Comment: Python lets you use either tab characters or space characters to indent to establish the level of nesting of a code block (or any combination of tabs and spaces, but mixing them is bad so people usually pick one and stick with it). If you use both tabs and spaces, Python is happy as long as you follow Python indentation rules, but different display environments (e.g. this one) may display the code as a mess with indentation all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your strategy selecting / iterating elements and may use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
...
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for e in soup.select('li[title]'):
    data.append({
        'link':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.get('title'),
        'price': e.select_one('.price').get_text()
    })
data
```

Process the [`list` of dicts to write your file or create a `dataframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv), ...

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<li class="cl-static-search-result" title="BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL 
      MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO">
        <a href="link1">
            <div class="title">BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO</div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,600</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Miami
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Honda Element">
        <a href=" link2 ">
            <div class="title">Honda Element</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,950</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Coral springs
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Mint Jeep">
        <a href=" link3 ">
            <div class="title">Mint Jeep</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$8,500</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Pompano
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
'''
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for e in soup.select('li[title]'):
    data.append({
        'link':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.get('title'),
        'price': e.select_one('.price').get_text()
    })
data
```

Comment: Hello- Where do i put this in my code?

Comment: Well, it's much more about understanding than just building things in. Try to understand what the example is doing in the first instance, then adapt it for your own purposes. a little hint, consider the loop and what is different about it.

Comment: This is working exactly as intended and it s super fast.
Question - Why did you use the get() method for the link and for title, but for the price, you used the select_one method?
I tried to add a line to get the location with the below:
'location': e.select_one('.location').get_text()
It is returning the location, but it s adding '\n and blank space in the result.

Comment: 1. Because `href` and `title` are attributes that contains the info, while price is only available as text. 2. simply add a parameter to `get_text(strip=True)` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked.
Just to understand please, how did you determine that href and title are attributes and price is text?

Comment: Not sure how the question is meant so just a reference to read about HTML fundamentals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started

Comment: Hello - I am still getting the error below, when I export to CSV. This is due to foreign characters I believe:
AttributeError: module 'unicodedata' has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: To keep the OP clean and near to the web-scraping part , this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. Thanks

Comment: I agree - I will raise a separate question..Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please assist with my other post/question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77284739/3618585