# How to retrieve nested data with BeautifulSoup? PART 2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I decided to post another question to address a new problem that rose after resolving the problem from [Part 1 of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259705/how-to-retrieve-nested-data-with-beautifulsoup).

My code below is supposed to retrieve the link, title, price, and location from web pages. It is working perfectly for the example below, but on certain pages, the code is either extracting few records or none at all. I am not sure why.

I am including the web example where code is not retrieving any or few records only.

##### Example (working)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<li class="cl-static-search-result" title="BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL 
      MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO">
        <a href="link1">
            <div class="title">BELLO HONDA ACCORD &quot;95 MIL MILLAS&quot;. REALMENTE COMO NUEVO</div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,600</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Miami
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Honda Element">
        <a href=" link2 ">
            <div class="title">Honda Element</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,950</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Coral springs
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Mint Jeep">
        <a href=" link3 ">
            <div class="title">Mint Jeep</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$8,500</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Pompano
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
'''
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for e in soup.select('li[title]'):
    data.append({
        'link':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.get('title'),
        'price': e.select_one('.price').get_text(),
        'location': e.select_one('.location').get_text(strip=True)
    })
data
```

Here is a non-working example; my code only retrieves the first row and skips the rest.

```
<li class="cl-static-search-result" title="Joyner 650">
        <a href="LINK1">
            <div class="title">Joyner 650</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$4,100</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Fernley
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="2009 Subaru legacy AWD!">
        <a href="LINK2">
            <div class="title">2009 Subaru legacy AWD!</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$6,300</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cl-static-search-result" title="2011 international durastar 4300 box truck">
        <a href="LINK3">
            <div class="title">2011 international durastar 4300 box truck</div>

            <div class="details">
                <div class="price">$21,900</div>
                <div class="location">
                    Lodi
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: the reason it is only returning the first one, is because you are only asking for the first in your loop with `for e in soup.select()`. You need to use something like `soup.findAll()` to get an array and then iterate over it.

Comment: @A_Patterson `select()` returns all matches, `select_one()` returns the first match.

Comment: There's no `.location` in the second LI.

Comment: Because of that, when I run your code I get an error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'**

Comment: Since our purpose here is not providing 1:1 assistance but instead [to build a knowledgebase/long-tail FAQ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), your question title should be oriented at helping people who got stuck the same place you did find your question and learn from its answers. A question that tries to implicitly answer _why_ there's a "part 2" (and how it differs from "part 1") would probably be much more helpful towards that end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the LIs don't have a location. You need to check for this.

```
for e in soup.select('li[title]'):
    price = e.select_one('.price')
    location = e.select_one('.location')
    data.append({
        'link':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.get('title'),
        'price': price.get_text() if price else '$unknown',
        'location': location.get_text(strip=True) if location else 'unknown'
    })
```

Result with the first html:

```
[{'link': 'link1',
  'location': 'Miami',
  'price': '$4,600',
  'title': 'BELLO HONDA ACCORD "95 MIL \n      MILLAS". REALMENTE COMO NUEVO'},
 {'link': ' link2 ',
  'location': 'Coral springs',
  'price': '$4,950',
  'title': 'Honda Element'},
 {'link': ' link3 ',
  'location': 'Pompano',
  'price': '$8,500',
  'title': 'Mint Jeep'}]
```

Result with the second html:

```
[{'link': 'LINK1',
  'location': 'Fernley',
  'price': '$4,100',
  'title': 'Joyner 650'},
 {'link': 'LINK2',
  'location': 'unknown',
  'price': '$6,300',
  'title': '2009 Subaru legacy AWD!'},
 {'link': 'LINK3',
  'location': 'Lodi',
  'price': '$21,900',
  'title': '2011 international durastar 4300 box truck'}]
```

Comment: Thank you - It is working! Question, just to understand, why my code broke when there is no location or price and does not skip to the next row in the loop?

Comment: Because `select_one()` doesn't return an element if it can't find it, and you can't get the text of a nonexistent element.

Comment: Hello - I actually noticed an issue, The URLs/links do not correspond to the titles. It seems the indexes are affected by this update.

Comment: I added the results I get with the two HTML samples in the question, it looks like it corresponds.

Comment: The links dont actually when I run on the full page - What could be the reason?

Comment: I guess the HTML structure isn't the same as what you've shown in the examples. Without an actual sample I can't guess any better.

Comment: My apologies - It s actually finr. When I sorted the CSV file, the first column was not selected, which of course messed up the order...Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: Question - How can I exclude rows where titles contains a year below let s say 2000 ?

Comment: Use `split()` to split the title into words. Check if the first word is numeric. If it is, convert to an integer and check if it's `>=2000`. If so, append to `data`.